# How can I do bottom sheet share component in kotlin compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-bottomsheetdialog

I'm trying to do a share component which is open the bottom like a modal bottom sheet in kotlin compose but I couldn't find a name and do it. How am I supposed to search to do this component in kotlin compose ? is there a any specific name for this ? can anyone help me out ?

it looks like this for example:

[image]

Comment: You may call it as send data to other apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try out this code:

```
val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    putExtra(
        Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
        "Your message that you want to send"
    )
    type = "text/plain"
}
val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)
val context = LocalContext.current
```

And in onClick of any button, start this intent to show bottom sheet for choosing app

```
Button(onClick={ context.startActivity(shareIntent) }){...}
```